# Laravel Database Migration foreign key error while using "php artisan migrate" command

Tags: laravel

Error:  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `epicit_cms`.`ep_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `ep_users` add constraint `ep_users_client_id_foreign` foreign key (`client_id`) references `ep_clients` (`id`) on delete cascade)

can someone explain what should do?

what i want to achieve is. if i want to delete a client it should delete users with the same client id too but i can't make it happen because i cant migrate my foreign key

Migration:

users table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('insertion')->nullable();
        $table->string('secondname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('client_id');  
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');            
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Clients table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('postal_code');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
}
```

Models:

User relation

```
public function Client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class );
}
```

Client relation

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's due to using `$table->uuid('id')->primary();` on `clients`, then trying to use `$table->integer('client_id');` on `users`. Column type needs to be the same for foreign keys to work.

Comment: Does you table clients still exist? Normally users is created first (and clients should be linked to users)

Comment: @TimLewis i looked into the database structure  " the $table->uuid('id')->primary();"on "clients" its  cha(36) so i changed from "$table->integer('client_id');" on "users"  to " $table->char('client_id', 36)->default(0); " and still no progress

Comment: @Dri372 no is there any way to change migration order clients before users

Comment: That "clients" table migration creates a table named "fields". (And would drop a table named "form_fields"). If you want to create a table before the "users" table is created rename the migration to a date before the users migration date

Comment: @TimLewis  my bad,  i just placed the correct code

Comment: That looks a little better. Still not sure why your tables are prefixed with `ep_`, but that might be a non-issue. So, in order to make this all work, you need to create your `clients` table before your `users` table, and make sure they have the same column type. Migrations are run in order of when they were created, or you can edit the filename to adjust the date. For example, `2021_06_01_120000_create_clients_table`, rename to `0000_00_00_000000_create_clieants_table` to ensure this file migration is run first. (Untested, but should work)

Comment: @TonyMoukhtar you should now have understood how to create your foreign link bu I really suggest you to "think reverse" that's more standard, link a cleint o a user.

Comment: @TimLewis Laravel, like other frameworks, comes with so many 'magics' that's always better to fulfill standard as maximum (create clients before users works but it's not the standard way ... nothing more). It's so easy to create a user_id in the table clients.

Comment: @TimLewis > but from my experience, is backwards. Either way, this conversation has no relevance to the core issues here ... 100% Ok with these 2 points.

Comment: Personal recommendation, avoid foreign constraints... It adds nothing to Laravel except this typo of problems... Have a good code and that is enough...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I used to agree with that statement; Laravel, with correct set-up, validation, relationships, etc etc can function entirely without FKs, but they have a lot of benefit, such as being able to call `$client->delete()`, and having all associated data also deleted (cascade). Having to handle that manually is extra coding, and you have messy data if you forget.

Comment: If you forget then you are not developing correctly. I have never used FKs with laravel as they are messy for a lot of things... Even for testing... Never had a si gle problem (when not using them) with data... I really recommend you to not use them, it will not add any value if you have good code.

Comment: @matiaslauriti *"If you forget then you are not developing correctly"* - **No developer is perfect**, and when working on a Team of developers, this can (and does) happen. Good peer-review practices should catch it, but even then, human errors happen. If you have a model that has multiple nested relationships, remembering to delete them all manually can be a pain. If you set up a proper FK, you can delete the top-level Model and everything else will cascade. It's more work to set-up, but less prone to issues/easier in the long run.

Comment: Well, I will still disagree, I have 7+ years professional experience, and I have 5+ with Laravel, again, I have never had a problem like this, only using FKs mess everything up... You need to have tests, that will help you with that.

Comment: @matiaslauriti It's ok to disagree, I've got slightly more experience with coding/Laravel (8/6 years), and like I said; I used to agree with that sentiment. I just find it hard to recommend not using a core feature of RDBMS, especially when your only real argument is your personal experience and "not having any issues"  ... Anyway, I think Tony Moukhtar has more than enough information to make their own decision.

Comment: Okay thank you guys for showing more then one way to do it. I fixed my code using this `$table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');` the way @sherifcoder did it. You can see it  in the first answer and i changed client tabel from this `$table->uuid('id')->primary();` to `$table->id('id');` .I did more research into `UUID` and what it appears to be that `UUID` it doesn't always work with `FKS. Again thank you for time

Answer (score 0):

change your migration like this

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('insertion')->nullable();
            $table->string('secondname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->foreignId('client_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onDelete('cascade');            
            $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure, your `Clients table` migration is running before `users table` migration.

And also your `foreign_key` field and your `id` should be of the same type, for example, if `clients.id` is `bigIncrements`, your foreign_key inside your `user table` also should be `bigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you guys for showing more then one way to do it. I fixed my code using this `$table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');` the way @sherifcoder did it and i changed client tabel from this `$table->uuid('id')->primary();` to `$table->id('id');` .I did more research into `UUID` and what it appears to be that `UUID` it doesn't always work with `FKS`. Again thank you for time